# Facebook Graph api PAGE - How to get video posts made by fans?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Sory for my english, i`m still learning.-

i´m developing an app using faceboko callback. All works fine, except when I receive videos.
These are atributes on my notification:

```
"post_id":"zzzzzzzzzz_yyyyyyyyyy",
"sender_name":"USER_NAME",
"video_id":yyyyyyyyyy,
"sender_id":xxxxxxxxxx,
"item":"video",
"verb":"add",
"link":"VIDEO_LINK",
"message":"EXAMPLE"
```

I need to get de video post, but when i try to get the post using post_id I get this error:

> Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'zzzzzzzzzz_yyyyyyyyyy' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

If I get directly the video using node graph.facebook.com/version/video_id it works fine but if i need to add o comment or something i dont know how to do it.

I was reading documentation and i couldnt find nothig about it.

note: if i go to facebook.com/zzzzzzzzzz_yyyyyyyyyy it works fine too.
Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolve the problem!
To get the post i had to build my own postId.

```
sender_id = xxxxxxxxxx
video_id = yyyyyyyyyy
```

The real post ID is compossed in the next way: SENDERID_VIDEOID

Then you will get a postId in this format:

```
xxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyy
```

The graph api call is:

```
graph.facebook.com/version/xxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyy
```